# What are the key concepts of solar energy?

Tags: energy

My goal is to compile a list of key concepts for learning solar energy. I aim to self-teach and eventually be able to experiment with building solar-powered products.

What items would be part of the list of key components of learning solar energy?

Comment: What is your background and how deep do you want to get into the physics of solar cells?

Answer (score 1):

here is an outline:

1) at the earth's surface, how much energy falls upon each square meter of area? 
2) what is the spectral content of that energy?
3) how does that energy vary with latitude, time of year, and time of day?
4) what are the existing ways of harvesting that energy?
5) what are the efficiency limits upon each harvesting method? 
6) what are the solved problems in the harvesting field?
7) what are the unsolved problems?